# JQuery UI Tabs not behaving as it should

Tags: jquery, html

I am familiar with JQuery UI Tabs but seem to have overlooked a detail here.

When you press the tab button `1` or `2` they work, but they do not hide the other tab and content. They just both go active which is not the normal behaviour of these?

The JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/Tp62K/

I cannot see the issue, perhaps somebody can enlighten me.

**The HTML**

```
<div id='subgroup-hotnav-panel-sec_1_subsec_12' style='border-style: dotted; border-color: green; border-width: 1px;'>
    <div id="content">
        :: subgroup-hotnav-panel-sec_1_subsec_12                                                
        <br />
        ItemsIDs: 

        <!-- TAB CONTROL BEGIN -->
        <ul id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs"> 
            <li><a href="#tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>                        
        </ul>
        <!-- TAB CONTROL END -->

        <!-- TAB CONTENT BEGIN -->

        <div id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1_content" class="tab-content">
            tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1_content                                    
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1">

                <h1>1</h1>
                <p>11</p>


            </div>

        </div>  

        <div id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2_content" class="tab-content">
            tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2_content                                    
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2">

                <h1>2</h1>
                <p>22</p>


            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code and removed some unwanted attributes. Though you can add them and test it. The code is

```
<div id="content">:: subgroup-hotnav-panel-sec_1_subsec_12
    <br />ItemsIDs:
    <!-- TAB CONTROL BEGIN -->
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- TAB CONTROL END -->
        <!-- TAB CONTENT BEGIN -->
        <div id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1">             tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_1_content
             <h1>1</h1>

            <p>11</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2">tabRef__sec_id_1_subsec_id_12_page_2_content
             <h1>2</h1>

            <p>22</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/n9J9Z/

Comment: Hope its of help to you.

Comment: hey thanks, i noticed my error eventually, i had wrapped the tab content panels with an extra div of which the script did not understand how to handle. Took a while but i found it. Thanks though!